# How can I "save" a list of class objects to my program in python 3?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, pandas, save

So I have a "dog" class which includes attributes like size, weight, color, etc. and I have added the different "dog" objects to a list/dictionary. That is all fine, but every time I stop running my program the list is cleared (which is normal). The question is - how can I keep this list data saved so when I re-run the program the list is still there and I can continue to add and edit the dogs on the list?

Also, if I were to store the data online, would it cost money for the server? I am a beginner here.

I have been looking into databases, pandas, and MySQL and I am pretty lost in the sea of info, so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Usually saving data online will cost you money, the reason being, someone has to pay for the servers where you will be storing your data.

There are two ways you can save your data, one is to write to a file and later retrieve it, and the other as you mentioned would be to save it to a db.

Comment: If you are saving it to a file, you can use, `csv`, `json`, `pickle` etc. Look up on how to do that. There are 100s of tutorials on them online. 

The second way is to set up a local database, for example, Postgres or Mongo database You can run them locally on your machine for the time being without having to pay a provider for them. Again, I would suggest looking up tutorials for them online. 

P.S. Whenever posting questions, it is best if you present the code you have written thus far as this better helps to understand how to guide you.

Comment: My recommendation: Try both, use `json` to save to disk, and use `postgres` to save to db.

Comment: raqib - thank you, do you have any experience with the mySQL community server? It seems to be free.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option to a DB is to write them out to a file and load the file back in on startup in json format using `json.dump()` and `json.load()` (or pickle if the data is more complicated). That can be much simpler than trying to incorporate a DB for simple situations.

You can find docs on these calls and the json module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage).

I have even used this to encode data and pass it over the network between programs.

You mentioned 'store the data online'. Is this running in the cloud or something. or are you just thinking of writing the data from your program out to the cloud for safe keeping or something? I cannot answer that since it depends on where (who with), what and how much.

Comment: Thank you. When I say 'store data online' I just mean I would like to be able to access the same set of data from anywhere, with any computer that has the program installed. I have thousands of 'dog' objects to store and edit, and I'm not always on the same computer.

Comment: @MajorTonality The obvious complication to what you just  described is access control. You likely do not want just anyone to be able to access it or even if that is okay you may not want it to be changable by anyone.   As a thought, you might be able to use something like bitbucket as a externally accessible storage. It would also give you some controls. I searched 'access bitbucket from python' and found ways to access it from python. Just a thought. I have never tried this.